# invalid syntax when attempting to append a series to my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I made a dataframe with some names of people I know, their relationship to me, and their birthday months. I want to append a new series into this dataframe with my mother.

```
import pandas as pd
entry_one = pd.Series({'Name':'Ryan',
                      'Relationship':'Self',               
                      'Birthday_Month' : 'April'})
entry_two = pd.Series({'Name':'Nickie',
                      'Relationship': 'Girlfriend',
                      'Birthday_Month':'February'})
entry_three = pd.Series({'Name':'Jeff',
                        'Relationship':'Friend',
                        'Birthday_Month':'August'})
entry_four = pd.Series ({'Name':'Mica',
                        'Relationship':'Friend',
                        'Birthday_Month':'November'})
entry_five = pd.Series ({'Name':'Andrew',
                        'Relationship':'Friend',
                        'Birthday_Month':'November'})

df = pd.DataFrame([entry_one, entry_two, entry_three, entry_four, entry_five])
df = df.set_index('Name')
df
df.append(pd.Series(data = ('Name':'Mom','Relationship':'Mother','Birthday_Month':'May')))
```

But I get the error

**Error**

> File "", line 1
>       df.append(pd.Series(data = ('Name':'Mom','Relationship':'Mother','Birthday_Month':'May')))
>                                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong type of brackets on the last line, it needs to be a dictionary and you need to turn on ignore)index to be able to append like this:

```
df.append(pd.Series(data = {'Name':'Mom','Relationship':'Mother','Birthday_Month':'May'}), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Please have a look at the other answer, it's quality is way better and yours does not add any important information.

Answer (score 0):

You need `dictionary` without `Name`, it is used as parameter `name` of `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([entry_one, entry_two, entry_three, entry_four, entry_five])
df = df.set_index('Name')
df = df.append(pd.Series(data = {'Relationship':'Mother','Birthday_Month':'May'},name='Mom'))
```

Dynamic solution without change `dictionary`, only filter out `Name` and select `name of Series` by `key of dict`:

```
d = {'Name':'Mom','Relationship':'Mother','Birthday_Month':'May'}
df = df.append(pd.Series(data = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k!= 'Name'},name=d['Name']))
```

---

```
print (df)
       Birthday_Month Relationship
Name                              
Ryan            April         Self
Nickie       February   Girlfriend
Jeff           August       Friend
Mica         November       Friend
Andrew       November       Friend
Mom               May       Mother
```

Or use `ignore_index=True` in [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) without `set_index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([entry_one, entry_two, entry_three, entry_four, entry_five])
d = {'Name':'Mom','Relationship':'Mother','Birthday_Month':'May'}
df = df.append(pd.Series(data=d), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  Birthday_Month    Name Relationship
0          April    Ryan         Self
1       February  Nickie   Girlfriend
2         August    Jeff       Friend
3       November    Mica       Friend
4       November  Andrew       Friend
5            May     Mom       Mother
```